# Multi-container docker on AWS - Nginx use host machine /etc/hosts resolver

Tags: nginx, docker, containers, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

> **Cross-Post from serverfault**
>
> Since I have seen similar issues posted here, I will X-post my question from ServerFault (https://serverfault.com/questions/855120/multi-container-docker-on-aws-nginx-use-host-machine-etc-hosts-resolver). I hope this
> is permitted.

I have a multi-container docker environment on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk with the following `Dockerrun.aws.json` file:

```
{ 
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2, 
    "containerDefinitions": [ 
      { 
        "name": "web", 
        "memoryReservation": 256, 
        "image": "my/nginx/repo/image",  
        "portMappings": [ 
          { 
            "hostPort": 80, 
            "containerPort": 80 
          } 
        ], 
        "links": [ 
          "api" 
        ], 
        "essential": true 
      }, 
      { 
        "name": "api", 
        "memoryReservation": 256, 
        "image": "my-api/repo", 
        "essential": true, 
        "portMappings": [ 
          { 
            "hostPort": 3000, 
            "containerPort": 80 
          } 
        ]
      } 
    ] 
  }
```

Ultimately I want the node app served by nginx to resolve requests to named addresses from linked containers, so in my `web` image (node app) I'd like to make a request to `http://api/some/resource` and let nginx resolve that to the api container.

Now, since docker adds a host entry for the api container due to the specified link, I want the nginx server to resolve addresses from the hosts `etc/hosts` file, however as I found out, nginx uses it's own resolver. After researching the issue a bit I found out that in non-Elastic Beanstalk multi-container solutions and with user-defined networks, the resolver would be provided by docker on `127.0.0.11`, however since it is currently not possible to define user-defined networks in the `Dockerrun.aws.json`, I keep looking for a different solution. The `links` can be resolved inside the container, `ping`ing api does work, however, nginx does it's own thing there.

I have read about `dnsmasq` as well, however, I wanted to get this running without installing this package, do I even have a choice here ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a service discovery topic, and I don't think this solution is in a right direction.

It is valid that `links` can be resolved to the App's IP; however, it must follow the starting order - App first and then Nginx. If the App recreates, or scales after Nginx started, `/etc/hosts` in Nginx won't be changed. It is possible to recreate the Nginx for updating the `/etc/hosts`, but then all the connections to the Nginx will be disconnected.

Since you are using Amazon Elastic Beanstalk, I think a better solution is to use [Consul](https://www.consul.io/) (Service Discovery) + [Registrator](https://github.com/gliderlabs/registrator) (Service Registration ) + Nginx (with SRV support, Plus or third party).

Personally, I have done a similar thing without AEB. I am using Docker Swarm (Service Discovery + Service Registration) + Nginx (with a modified [HAproxy-SRV](https://github.com/elasticio/haproxy-srv))

I hope this answer can help your decision.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have decided to circumvent the issue by deciding to go with two separate environments in EB. One houses the web container, the second the api and it's dependencies. That way I have separation of concerns and can access the api via it's public url. This seems like the easiest and cleanest solution, with the added benefit that it might scale better since the API container cluster might scale disproportionally to the web container.